# Syntax error in AngularJS factory service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following factory service in angularjs:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('gameApp_services').factory('sessionService', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        set:function(key, value) {
            return sessionStorage.setItem(key,value);
        },
        get:function() {
            return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
        },
        destroy:function() 
            return sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
        }
    };
}]).factory('loginService', function($http,$location,sessionService) {
    return {
        login: function(data, scope) {
            var $promise = $http.post("lib/action.php", data); //send data to action.php
            $promise.then(function(msg) {
                var uid = msg.data;
                if(uid) {
                    //scope.msgtxt='Correct information';
                    sessionService.set('user', uid);
                    $location.path('/game');
                } else {
                    scope.msgtxt='Incorrect information';
                    $location.path('/firstpage');
                }
            });
        },
        logout:function() {
            sessionService.destroy('user');
            $location.path('/firstpage');
        }
    }
});
```

When I run this, I get this error message:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error


return sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
```

How should the syntax look like? Anyone who can help me? I have no I idea.

Comment: You're missing the opening `{` on the function.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing bracket after destroy.

this should work. '

```
angular.module('gameApp_services').factory('sessionService', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        set:function(key, value) {
            return sessionStorage.setItem(key,value);
        },
        get:function() {
            return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
        },
        destroy:function() {
            return sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
        }
    };
}]).factory('loginService', function($http,$location,sessionService) {
    return {
        login: function(data, scope) {
            var $promise = $http.post("lib/action.php", data); //send data to action.php
            $promise.then(function(msg) {
                var uid = msg.data;
                if(uid) {
                    //scope.msgtxt='Correct information';
                    sessionService.set('user', uid);
                    $location.path('/game');
                } else {
                    scope.msgtxt='Incorrect information';
                    $location.path('/firstpage');
                }
            });
        },
        logout:function() {
            sessionService.destroy('user');
            $location.path('/firstpage');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I forgot a { in sessionStorage.removeItem.